# VS2015 error lnk2001 unresolved external symbol __imp___vsnprintf

Tags: visual-studio-2015, unresolved-external

Recently, I change my IDE from VS2013 to VS2015.

With all the platform tool set are set to VS2015(v140), I got the error:

```
error lnk2001 unresolved external symbol __imp___vsnprintf
```

I add the code as follows:

```
#if _MSC_VER>=1900
    #define STDC99
    extern "C" { FILE __iob_func[3] = { *stdin,*stdout,*stderr }; }
#else
    #ifndef snprintf
    #define snprintf _snprintf
    #endif
#endif
```

but I still get errors as follows:

```
cocos2d-x\cocos\platform/win32/CCStdC-win32.h(54): error C4430: missing type specifier 
- int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int (compiling source file ..\audio\win32
\MciPlayer.cpp)

cocos2d-x\cocos\platform/win32/CCStdC-win32.h(54): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';'
before '{' (compiling source file ..\audio\win32\MciPlayer.cpp)

cocos2d-x\cocos\platform/win32/CCStdC-win32.h(54): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' 
before identifier '__iob_func' (compiling source file ..\audio\win32\MciPlayer.cpp)

cocos2d-x\cocos\platform/win32/CCStdC-win32.h(54): error C2447: '{': missing function 
header (old-style formal list?) (compiling source file ..\audio\win32\MciPlayer.cpp)

C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10150.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(28): 
error C2378: 'FILE': redefinition; symbol cannot be overloaded with a typedef 
(compiling source file ..\editor-support\cocostudio\CCActionFrameEasing.cpp)

C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10150.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h(287): 
error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'FILE' (compiling source file ..\base\s3tc.cpp)
```

In VS2015:

```
typedef struct _iobuf
{
    void* _Placeholder;
} FILE;

#define stdin  (__acrt_iob_func(0))
#define stdout (__acrt_iob_func(1))
#define stderr (__acrt_iob_func(2))
```

In VS2013:

```
struct _iobuf {
    char *_ptr;
    int   _cnt;
    char *_base;
    int   _flag;
    int   _file;
    int   _charbuf;
    int   _bufsiz;
    char *_tmpfname;
    };
typedef struct _iobuf FILE;

#define stdin  (&__iob_func()[0])
#define stdout (&__iob_func()[1])
#define stderr (&__iob_func()[2])
```

There are two definitions for FILE. How could I fix it?

Comment: Adding __iob_func yourself just ensures that you won't get the correct linker errors.  And no answer.  Properly document this question by telling us what you see when you use the linker's /VERBOSE option.